Runnig allure serve to generate reports gives Error: spawn EINVAL
>allure serve

node:internal/child_process:421
    throw new ErrnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn EINVAL
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:421:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:761:9)
    at module.exports (C:\qa\wdio-tests\node_modules\allure-commandline\index.js:7:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\qa\wdio-tests\node_modules\allure-commandline\bin\allure:5:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  errno: -4071,
  code: 'EINVAL',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Node.js v20.12.2,
package.json values:
allure-commandline: "^2.28.0",
@wdio/allure-reporter: "^7.33.0",
@wdio/cli": "^7.7.4",
@wdio/cucumber-framework": "7.34.0",

Tried with node 18,
deleted node modules folder and re-install them no help, the error persists. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

the issue is fixed in latest allure-commandline@2.29.0
https://github.com/orgs/allure-framework/discussions/2518

Node released a breaking change due to a high-security vulnerability.
Now, to use the spawn and spawnAsync functions to run .cmd or .bat files, you need to specifically provide the { shell: true } option; otherwise, Node will throw the EINVAL exception.
Since allure-commandline@2.29.0, Allure added the required option, and the fix was tested using Node 18, 20 and 21.
If updating allure-commandline to the latest version (2.29.0 or above) doesn't help, please ensure you're using the latest available (minor & patch) version of Node JS.

with node version 20.10.0 it worked for me.
